# Blazor using Linux with Nginx WebSockets issue

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm hosting Blazor web application (.NET 7) on Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS VPS using Nginx/1.18.0.

Somehow it works fine on Firefox or mobile Safari, on Chrome (both desktop and mobile) I'm expiriencing WebSocket connection issue:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://website.com/_blazor?id=mNSKPSW6ZpgU-tT9g-YPLw' failed: 
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
connect @ blazor.server.js:1
_startTransport @ blazor.server.js:1
_createTransport @ blazor.server.js:1
_startInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-11-20T12:03:14.398Z] Information: (WebSockets transport) There was an error with the transport.
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-11-20T12:03:14.398Z] Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
```

I tried [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-5.0#linux-with-nginx), but no luck.

Program.cs code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for soundion scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
 server_name   website.com *.website.com;
 location / {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
 proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}server {
    if ($host = website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


 listen 80;
 server_name   website.com *.website.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74444687/20339875 it's been a while I configured nginxn on Linux, here's how I did it.

Comment: Have you tried: proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;

Comment: Yes, it's included to my nginx config.

Comment: You have proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll give it a try and respond later.

Comment: I think this might help too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67344108/20339875

Comment: Yes, already seen this one. Changed proxy_set_header Connection $http_upgrade to proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade", unfortunately didn't do the trick.

Comment: 'proxy_set_header Connection upgrade' didn't help either.

Comment: That's interesting. When you find out what inhibits the WebSockets please post here.